# how to insert node in Circular Linked list in C

Tags: c, linked-list, circular-list

Can someone explain the 'while part' of the code?-  in the main() head is declared as struct node pointer initialized with value NULL. and a node is inserted by calling function = push(&head,12)

```
void push(struct Node **head_ref, int data)
{ 
    struct Node *ptr1 = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); 
    struct Node *temp = *head_ref; 
    ptr1->data = data; 
    ptr1->next = *head_ref; 
    if (*head_ref != NULL) 
    { 
        while (temp->next != *head_ref)
            temp = temp->next; 
        temp->next = ptr1; 
    }
    else
        ptr1->next = ptr1; /*For the first node */

    *head_ref = ptr1;
}
```

Comment: In the answer below I attempt to address your question, but if it is insufficient, please flag me (@ryyker) in a comment with any questions :))

Comment: The lack of a pointer to the last node in the circular list (provided by the `->prev` pointer in a doubly-linked list) requires that after adding the new 1st node, you have to traverse the entire list to find the last node and update the `->next` pointer so it points to the new 1st node. (lesson: always keep a `tail` pointer or make the list a `doubly-linked` list to preserve O(1) insertions)

Answer (score 2):

*Can someone explain the 'while part' of the code?*

The `while()` part (also described in section `2.)` below.) is to look for the node which points to the current *head node* so that the *new node* can be inserted just before it. While in the loop, notice that as nodes are found, and they are not yet the *head node*, they are *incremented* so as to prepare for the insertion when *head node* is finally located.

The last expression in the routine:

```
*head_ref = ptr1;
```

Is to handle the case described by section `1.)` in the general steps below.

General approach for the following initial conditions:

1. Linked List is empty:
   a)  since new_node is the only node in CLL, make a self loop.
   new_node->next = new_node;
   b) change the head pointer to point to new node.
   *head_ref = new_node;
2. New node is to be inserted just before the head node:
   (a) Find out the last node using a loop.
   while(current->next != *head_ref)
   current = current->next;
   (b) Change the next of last node.
   current->next = new_node;
   (c) Change next of new node to point to head.
   new_node->next = *head_ref;
   (d) change the head pointer to point to new node.
   *head_ref = new_node;
3. New node is to be  inserted somewhere after the head:
   (a) Locate the node after which new node is to be inserted.
   while ( current->next!= *head_ref &&
   current->next->data data)
   {   current = current->next;   }
   (b) Make next of new_node as next of the located pointer
   new_node->next = current->next;
   (c) Change the next of the located pointer
   current->next = new_node;

Details and implementation for doing this are shown in this [example code](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-insert-for-circular-linked-list/)